# Is ものを similar to けど?

Tags: word-choice, jlpt

Another sentence from my JLPT practise book, this time in a section explaining the use of `ものを`.

> 借金{しゃっきん}で困{こま}っていた友人{ゆうじん}を、助{たす}けようと思{おも}えば助{たす}けられた**ものを**、見捨{みす}ててしまった。

I *think* this sentence is saying, "My friend who was having debt problems / if I had thought about helping I could have helped / but I forgot about it."

If I'm on the right track in the meaning, then I'm not sure what `ものを` is bringing to the party here.

Is this sentence equivalent:

> 借金{しゃっきん}で困{こま}っていた友人{ゆうじん}を、助{たす}けようと思{おも}えば助{たす}けられた**けど**、見捨{みす}ててしまった。

If so, what extra meaning does `ものを` have that would make one choose to use it over `けど`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

～ものを (sense [1]-1 in [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%92&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0na)) is similar to ～けど, but using ～ものを signifies the unsatisfactory feeling of the speaker.  In your example, I think that using ～ものを instead of ～けど expresses the regret of the speaker.

Comment: Just to be clear, if the sentence used けど instead, it would still be perfectly grammatical? I just want to be sure that strictly the only difference is the sense of disappointment.

Comment: @DaveMG: It is grammatical.  But けど is slightly informal.  けれど or けれども has the formality corresponding to ものを, and in these cases, I think that the only difference is the sense of dissatisfaction or disappointment.

Comment: Sorry, one more question... is ものを used in spoken Japanese, or is ot more confined to written Japanese?

Comment: @DaveMG: It is used both in speech and in writing, but I think that it is a little too formal to use casually.  Others may have different opinions.