# Grammar - ちょうど as an adverb and を verb omission (actual ところを)

Tags: grammar

[Source](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000081/files/46600_33648.html)

> それで日本人ならば、**ちょうど**花見とか月見とか言う処**を**、蛙どもは雲見をやります。
> Frogs do cloud seing in the exact same way that Japanese people do flower viewing or moon viewing.

Is ちょうど modifying やります? What is omitted after を? How would you translate this literally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- No, this ちょうど modifies 言う. It means "exactly", "precisely", "surely" or "just (like)".
- Nothing is omitted after this を. This を is not an object marker but an [archaic conjunctive particle](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa010018.htm) that means "and" or "but" depending on the context. We still commonly use ところを in modern Japanese, and this should be learned as a grammar pattern.

  - [Does ところを always mean the same thing as のに? What is the difference between ところへ and ところに?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19173/5010)
  - [Use of のところ for comparison?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84644/5010)
  - [Bunpro: ところを (JLPT N1)](https://bunpro.jp/grammar_points/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E3%82%92)
  - [jisho.org: ところを](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E3%82%92)

> How would you translate this literally?

それで日本人ならば、ちょうど花見とか月見とか言う処を、蛙どもは雲見をやります。

- So if (they were) Japanese, (this is exactly a situation where) they would say cherry watching or moon watching, but frogs do cloud watching.
- Therefore, (in situations) where Japanese people would (surely) say (let's do) cherry watching or moon watching, frogs do cloud watching.